# Issue Initializing GridDB Cluster with Docker

Tags: griddb

I'm working on setting up a GridDB cluster using Docker on my local machine. My objective is to establish a simple setup with GridDB and a React CRUD application to manage the database. However, I'm stuck at the cluster initialization step due to an error that prevents me from proceeding.

I executed the official documentation steps as follows:

```
docker network create griddb-net docker pull griddbnet/griddb docker run --network griddb-net --name griddb-server -d -t griddbnet/griddb docker pull griddbnet/griddb-react-crud docker run --network griddb-net --name griddb-react-crud -p 2828:2828 -d -t griddbnet/griddb-react-crud docker exec -it griddb-server gs_stat -u admin/admin
```

At this point, I encounter the following error, which prevents me from interacting further with the GridDB server:

```
[SystemService] INITIALIZATION FAILED. PLEASE CHECK NETWORK SETTINGS AND CLUSTER CONFIGURATION.
```

What could be the possible issue for the failure to connect to the cluster? All leads are welcome.